# changing pixel color in C#

Tags: c#, .net, colors, system.drawing

hello i'm working on program that read whole image and change the color of green line to red line for example i have this image [image: this image] and i want the c# program get the green pixels and convert it to red 
i tried this code : `

```
public Bitmap ReadImgPixel(Bitmap img)
{
        Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(img,img.Width,img.Height);
        int a1 = img.Width;
        int a2 = img.Height;
        System.Drawing.Color[,] pixels = new System.Drawing.Color[a1,a2];

        for (int i = 0;i< img.Width ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < img.Height; j++)
            {

               System.Drawing.Color pxl = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                if (pxl != System.Drawing.Color.White)
                {
                    pic.SetPixel(i, j, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                }

            }

        }
         return pic;
     }
```

but the result was the whole image is changing to red how to fix it !!

Comment: To pre-empt the next question, about why is it so slow, that's because you're using `SetPixel`. You should be using `LockBits` and manipulating the raw bits directly. Therefore, little reason to worry about making this code work. Also, you're looping through the image sub-optimally: the outer loop should be y, the inner loop should be x.

Comment: If the case is always specifically "green to red on a white background", you could do this in a really funny way by switching the R and G components of each colour. That'll even preserve the fade to white ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried debugging (you could have easily found out why all pixels turned red)? Your whole picture turns red because the `if` statement is always `true`.

The reason this happens is because you are comparing structs. However, your pixel `name` will not say `White` (what you are comparing to), but it will contain a string with the `hex` value of your color (e.g. `ffffff`). So it is never equal, because the objects are different. Therefore, since you want to see if the `ARGB` values are the same, you have to compare these.

Change your statement to this to compare the `ARGB` values:

```
if (pxl.ToArgb() != Color.White.ToArgb())
```

Also make sure you check [Cody Gray's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679972/changing-pixel-color-in-c-sharp/43680088#comment74405933_43679972), since your code is absolutely not efficient. If efficiency is important to you, try a different approach, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: man its work !!! thank you but i didn't get it what different between my statement and yours ??

Comment: @eliemardelly I just added an explanation as well. I hope that makes the difference clear to you? Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Designing the `==` operator to compare "string" equality for the `Color` object was a rather foolish design. It occupies a middle ground between reference equality and value equality that makes almost entirely worthless and always confusing.